# Pattern matching requirement

Tags: asp.net

We have a requirement wherein we will have to periodically monitor stream of data and include them in particular buckets. What will be the best language or tool to implement such requirement ?

Comment: This is not the right site to ask such a question. Try here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Kafka 
"Kafka™ is used for building real-time data pipelines and streaming apps"
https://kafka.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could use scala if you have very complicated pattern, but if it's simple, it's a perfect match to use a message broker like RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my humble experience I would reccomend nodejs, it works nicely with sockets and streams, you can implement thing fast, and performance are good too (async I/O). If you are not familiar with it think of it as a js engine with socket/HTTP support and async I/O. Performnces are really good. If you need *really fast* or peculiar things you can even extend with C++, but I think it's not necessary. Give a look https://nodejs.org/en/